# Intellij Tomcat Server Configuration - multiple HTTP connectors found ISSUE

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm configuring the first Tomcat Server on my Intellij setup. I get the following error:

[image]

Do you know why Intellij is throwing this warning?

Answer (score 1):

The warning is returned by Intellij when it doesn't like the configuration on server.xml... that I have previously created for https connector purposes.

So I have a connector for HTTP and an additional connector configuration for HTTPS.
Idea will replace the port for the first one which is HTTP in this case - which is totally fine for my scenario.

Anyway, I ended up adding a brand new cleaned up Tomcat instance specifically for the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

In my `server.xml` there was this:

```xml
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  ...
  <Service name="Catalina">
    ...
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    ...
    <Connector
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        port="5001"
        maxThreads="200"
        scheme="https"
        secure="true"
        SSLEnabled="true"
        sslProtocol="TLS"
        sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
        keystoreFile="..."
        keystorePass="..."
        keyAlias="..."
        clientAuth="false"/>

    <Connector
      port="5002"
      protocol="HTTP/1.1"
      connectionTimeout="20000"
      redirectPort="5001"/>
    ...
  </Service>
  ...
</Server>
```

I commented out the first `Connector` and the warning went instantly.